# How to easily expose all private members of a C++ class I am a friend of?

Tags: c++, private, friend

I have the following classes:

```
class Foo
{
friend class FriendFoo;
private:
    int private_number1;
    int private_number2;
    int private_function1();
    int private_function2();
};

class FriendFoo
{
public:
    Foo& foo;
    FriendFoo(Foo& foo_) : foo(foo_)
    {
    }

    // I don't want to write the following adaptors:
    int getPrivateNumber1()
    {
        return foo.private_number1;
    }

    int getPrivateNumber2()
    {
        return foo.private_number2;
    }

    int private_function1()
    {
        return foo.private_function1();
    }

    int private_function2()
    {
        return foo.private_function2();
    }
};
```

## Problem:

I want to access all the private members of `Foo` from outside via `FriendFoo`, but I don't want to modify the class `FriendFoo` whenever private members of `Foo` change (or another one is added).
Ideally, I would like to get rid of all the adaptors. Is there a way how to achieve this?

## Background:

I want to use this for unit testing of private methods and I chose the "friend" way of doing it.
Please, don't discuss/criticize testing of private methods here, a lot was written about it.
I just want to find a solution to the concrete technical problem presented.

Comment: If all your functions are of the same signature, you can always add the functions to a private vector; but I don't understand why you don't want to change friendFoo; You're migrating effort of maintaining tests from the test object to the tested object, which is the wrong place for it.

Comment: I'm itching to create the [trust-issues] tag.

Comment: It's typically for this kind of issue that most of unit testing framework allowing test of private function parse code, instrument code and generate helpers

Comment: @UKMonkey I don't want to move code from FriendFoo (addition for testing) to Foo (tested object). I just want to make FriendFoo clever enough to be able to handle modifications of Foo.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one *legal* way of accessing `private` members of a class, which also has the advantage that there is zero source code pollution in the code to you want to test. Consider

```
class Foo
{
    int bar;
};
```

Then in your testing code build a "penetrator" using

```
template<typename Y, typename Y::type Member>
struct Penetrator
{
    friend typename Y::type get(Y){
        return Member;
    }
};
```

For each member of `Foo` you want to read, define a simple class

```
struct Foo_bar
{ 
    typedef int Foo::*type;
    friend type get(Foo_bar);
};
```

and an appropriate specialisation:

```
template struct Penetrator<Foo_bar, &Foo::bar>;
```

You can then write

```
int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.*get(Foo_bar()) = 1; // write a value to it.
}
```

Comment: @bolov: good point. For portability, you need to define the "simple class" I've now added. The above should compile now "out of the box".

Comment: Congratulations. You managed to make me confused with ~5 lines of templates, which I arrogantly thought could not happen at this point. Very smart ideea. +1

Comment: I don't have a problem with polluting a code a little bit, adding a friend keyword is OK for me. But if a private member is added to Foo, now I have to add an adaptor function (and I want to get rid of doing this). But you suggest to create a struct and a template which is even more work. I'm afraid that this is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see you accessing the private members directly without any adaptors using the friend approach is if:

- the class in question may be derived from
- your unit testing framework allows you to define individual test cases within a class body (as methods)

These restrictions may be a deal-breaker for you.

The proposed solution:

```
// foo.h
class Tester;
class Foo
{
private:
    friend class Tester;
    int private_number_1;
    int private_function_1() { return 0; }
};

// foo_test.cpp
#include <cassert>

class Tester : public Foo
{
public:
    void test_case_1() { assert(private_number_1 == 0); }
    void test_case_2() { assert(private_function_1() == 0); }
};

void main()
{
    Tester ff;
    ff.test_case_1();
    ff.test_case_2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just relabel private public, with a comment that access is for testing.

Then put it back to private when you are done. You can even use #if to
toggle it.

Comment: That makes the binary you're testing different from the one you deliver, which is unacceptable in many environments.

Comment: Are you sure? You might be right, but the obvious way of writing a simple C++ type compiler would only put the public/private check in the parse phase.

Comment: The fact that you suggest `#if` to switch something between `public` and `private` means that you must compile separately for the test and for release, doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, maybe I see what you mean - it's only in the header, so you `#define TEST_VISIBILITY public` before including from the test code, but still link against the one binary.  Yes, that could work.  Perhaps add a little example to you answer, for others as slow as I am?

Comment: does it mean to compile class `Foo` with `private_number1` as private, and compile the tester class linking to `Foo` with header files marking `private_number1` as public?